# How do I sum the "money" values in the Foreach loop in my project with Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, swiftui-list

I created a loop with foreach. My data is coming through firebase. How do I sum the "money" values in the Foreach loop in my project with Swift? Please help!

[TODOS.swift / Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruaYE.png)

[IncomeList.swift / Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOlbc.png)

Comment: Put the code into the question as text, please - linking to code in images is pretty horrible for us and also for search engines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Text(String("\(self.session.items.map({ $0.money }).reduce(0, +))"))
```

could you try insert above code below "List {" code line in "TODOS.swift / Image"?

Comment: Heey! Since I was just starting to learn, I couldn't find a simple resource on the subject. Really thank you so much. It worked great! You are awesome.